# Can't recognize the microphone on an Hp Pavilion dv 2000la

Tags: 11.10, sound, microphone, hp-pavilion

I was trying to have a conversation via skype this morning, when surprise there was no sound; so i opened sound settings to see what could i do about it, and i found this [image: sound settings, input tab, mic not working]
and the mic wasn't responding to any sound but instead to some hits on the laptop just at the left side of the track pad(where is located the hard drive), so i opened the laptop to see if there was something wrong with the cable or the conector but everithing was just fine.

then, I use a pen drive with ubuntu 11.10 to launch sound setting from the gui of the installer to verify that ther was nothing wrong with he hardware but with the software instead; I opened sound setting from the installer first screen, and the mic was working fine.

So i suppose that i have a problem with the analog input and the internal mic, I suppose that ubuntu is taking both options as if I were choosing always internal input; that's my theory, the questions are how do i solve it?, how do i reinstall the mic software that is causing the problem? because i don't want to install ubuntu all over again just by a not recognized mic.

Here some technical info as requested below:

I'm using a Hp pavilion dv 2000la, and ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)

Running `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub [8086:27a0] (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a2] (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a6] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 [8086:27d0] (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 [8086:27d4] (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 [8086:27d6] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27b9] (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller [8086:27df] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7 Family) SATA AHCI Controller [8086:27c5] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 02)
08:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection [8086:1092] (rev 02)
08:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller [1180:0832]
08:09.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter [1180:0822] (rev 19)
08:09.2 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter [1180:0592] (rev 0a)
08:09.3 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller [1180:0852] (rev 05)
```

Here are the codecs foud in /proc/asound/card0 and /proc/asound/intel: [Codecs card0 and intel](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LrKNbusQbYc2XoPfNhSrJrudCAH5fU8_7elv1wD_s5Q/edit)
thanks a lot for your answers, i apologize english is not my first language.
GOD bless you guys

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I fixed non-working microphone on my HP Pavillion tx1000:

Open *alsamixer* by typing in terminal window:

```
alsamixer
```

If you have a built-in sound card and microphone, you'll see it listed in the upper left corner.  There should be the following labels in the upper left corner of the alsamixer:

```
Card: HDA NVidia   
Chip: Realtek ALC861-VD   
View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All  
Item: Master [dB gain: 0.00]
```

The *"View"* is important.  The default screen is for PLAYBACK settings (your speakers), the *"F4"* is what you need for microphone settings tuning.

Press <kbd>F4</kbd> and in the settings for *Capture* make sure  *"Capture"* is non-zero.

The setting next to *"Capture"* called *"Input Source"* is what fixed the microphone problem for me. Navigate to *"Input Source"* and press <kbd>↑</kbd> (up arrow key) to switch between different options - *ATAPI Mic* worked for me.

By default, after installation of Ubuntu 11.10 I had *"Front Mic"* there.